# Simple Kafka Producer implementation in Java depends on SLF4J

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka

I have written what I believe to be a bare-bones implementation of a Kafka Producer in Java.

```
package com.mycompany.kafkaexample.KafkaExample;


import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;

import java.util.Properties;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hello Kafka");
        
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:29092");
        properties.setProperty("default.topic", "hello-world-topic");
        
        
        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);
        
        String topicName = "hello-world-topic";
        String key = "";
        String message = "Hello Kafka! (Message String)";
        
        ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(topicName, key, message);
        
        producer.send(producerRecord);
        
        producer.close();

    }

}
```

Please note: I am not totally sure if this will work yet as I haven't been able to compile it.

The reason for that is the following error:

```
The type org.slf4j.Logger cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer
```

This suggests to me that something in Kafka is referencing `slf4j` - but why?

- I didn't include any code that does anything to do with `slf4j`, at least I haven't *knowingly* done this.
- So why do I get an error message about it?
- If something internal to Kafka references `slf4j`, then why doesn't the relevant Kafka code sort out the `import ...slf4j` itself? (Why do I have to do something about it?)
- What is causing this error?

I am building this project using Maven.

My `pom.xml`: (Also please note that I have very little understanding of what this does. It was mostly generated for me, although the Kafka dependency was added by me.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany.kafkaexample</groupId>
  <artifactId>KafkaExample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>KafkaExample</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: yes kafka uses sl4j-api, and the dependency is defined in the kafka's pom.xml. But it should have been resolved by maven. It looks like you didnt build it correctly. Did you run `mvn clean install` before trying to execute the code?

Comment: By the way, `maven.compiler.target` should be set to `11`... Kafka has dropped java 7 support long ago

Comment: I would have thought `11` was Java (language) Version 11. Should it not be set to something more up to date such as 17 or even 20? Setting it to 17 results in another error: `invalid target release: 17`

Comment: Spoke too soon. Following the above instructions doesn't make any difference.

Comment: You're not required to use most recent version, no. As answered, you'd often down compile, depending on where code gets ran (not only based on your local machine)... Plus, Maven itself defaults to 1.8

Comment: @OneCricketeer Required? No. But it would be sensible to use a LTS version (the current one) by default.

Answer (score 0):

> <sub>Sidenote: I would not recommend learning Kafka, Java, and Maven all at the same time. Kafka Clients exist in many different (simpler) languages.</sub>

Firstly, replace `kafka_2.13` by `kafka-clients`. The former is the broker server library, not the producer/consumer API.

Regarding the question, yes, Kafka clients use [`slf4j-api`](https://slf4j.org/manual.html), but it is only at `runtime` Maven scope, meaning you **do** need to provide it on your own. ([This guide uses Gradle, but same concepts apply](https://developer.confluent.io/get-started/java/))
This is only a facade library, and requires you adding an implementation logger, such as `reload4j`, `logback`, or `log4j2` (recommended).

So, one of these need to be added to your POM. For example, refer log4j2 documentation

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html#migrating-from-log4j-1-x-to-2-x

Then once added, you will also need to create a `src/main/resources/log4j2.xml` file, such as

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="DEBUG">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="org.apache.kafka" level="INFO"/>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And, if that works, you should be able to run the code and get the next problem...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value null for configuration key.serializer: must be non-null.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.appendSerializerToConfig(ProducerConfig.java:579)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:290)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:317)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:302)
```

Which requires you to add these two lines

```
properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
```

And you ideally replace `System.out` usage with an slf4j logger.

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);
// LOG.info("Hello world")
```

Comment: Makes no difference. I have tried two ways: Directly from the command line with `mvn` and using a Maven project from within Eclipse

Comment: I use Intellij or vscode, and not used Eclipse in years, but I don't think the IDE is causing the problem

Comment: To add further clarification: I find that I can compile using the POM from a Linux machine via the command line with Maven. I cannot run it. That is a different issue. From a Windows machine with Eclipse, I cannot compile. The project type within Eclipse is Maven, using the same POM. Both `javac` support version 17, although obviously being two different OS the compilers are not the same binary. Very weird.

Comment: I'm trying your pom on a Mac right now. I'll get back to you

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Was able to run your code. See updated answer